# Javascript Closure Scope

Tags: javascript

I was reading the "Closures" section on the w3schools JavaScript tutorial and I don't understand how the last example works.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

The goal is to create a "private" variable `counter` that only the `add` function can manipulate. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Counting with a local variable.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>

<p id="demo">0</p>

<script>
var add = (function  outer() {
    var counter = 0;
    return function inner() {return counter += 1;}
})();

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I edited the two anonymous functions and named them `outer` and `inner` so they can be more easily referenced. Here is a link of the code in action:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_counter3

So initially the variable `add` is assigned to a self-invoking function expression. This would execute the `outer` function one time and set the `counter` to 0. When the button is clicked, `myFunction` is called and this puts the returned value of the `add` function, the updated `counter` value, inside the p tag. So clicking on the button increments the value of the `counter` variable by 1 on every onclick event of the button. I don't understand how the value of the `counter` value is affected by the `outer` and the `inner` functions. This is how I (wrongly) understand it:

When the `add` function is called by the `myFunction` function (upon an onclick event of the button), first the `outer` function would set the `counter` variable to 0 by the following statement:

```
var counter = 0;
```

Intuitively I would think that the return value of the `add` function would invoke the `inner` function (especially because I can see this code works) but I don't get how. That is one question I have. If I just accept it then the `inner` function would increment the `counter` variable by 1. I can see how this makes sense for clicking the button that calls the `myFunction` function once. For the second time the button is clicked I don't understand how it doesn't reset. I feel that before the second click the `counter` variable is 1 and then on the click the `outer` function resets the `counter` variable back to 0 with this line again:

```
var counter = 0;
```

and then the `inner` function is invoked. Since the `inner` function is nested in the `outer` function, it is in the scope to access the `counter` variable and then increases it from 0 back to 1. What am I not understanding about this?

I feel I might not quite understand how the `return` statement on a function works but I'm not sure. Is the `add` variable just the `inner` function only because that is what is returned? And how is it invoked if it is inside a `return` statement? I don't get how `var counter = 0;` is not executed on every click of the button when `myFunction` is invoked.

I thought `myFunction` invokes the `add` function and that executes `outer` function, which executes `var counter = 0;` and then the `inner` function gets returned and invoked and that increases the `counter` variable.

I don't quite get if returning a function would invoke the function either. I also don't know if the creation and assignment of the `add` variable had anything to do with how this works. I didn't think so at first but who knows? I don't understand this so anything is possible to me right now.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't get how var counter = 0; is not executed on every click of the button when myFunction is invoked.

Because the code

```
var add = (function  outer() {
    var counter = 0;
    return function inner() {return counter += 1;}
})();
```

only executes once.  It returns an immediate function, storing it into the `add` variable, which you then assign to something else later (using `= Add()`).  Notice the ending pair of parentheses?  That's what causes the outer function *to execute immediately,* one time.

When the function in the `add` variable is assigned, it *returns the inner function.*  That inner function is what gets executed when `myFunction` runs.

The only other thing you need to know is that *the inner function has access to the `counter` variable in the outer function,* due to the closure.

Comment: Thanks Robert Harvey! That makes a lot more sense now. I wasn't understanding what the add variable actually stored but it is more clear now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You are confused because you are thinking add is:

```
var add = (function  outer() {
             var counter = 0;
             return function inner() {return counter += 1;}
           })();
```

**but actually add is:**

```
add= function inner() {return counter += 1;}
```

because this function is what outer self executing function is returning and it is assigned to add.

Outer function is executed only once (when it is returning inner function) and initialized variable "counter" to 0.

Child function can access parent function's variable, and each time we are calling add, it just increment "counter" by 1.

Answer (score 1):

**add** is holding a *reference* to the function **inner** i.e. function returned from **outer** function.

**Closures** is when a function remembers is its *lexical scope* even when invoked from outside that *lexical scope.*

So inner remembers its scope and thus able to access the **counter** variable .
Thus , its **inaccessible** outside directly and acts as **private**.
But **add** or **inner** can  manipulate it.

As soon as you refer **add** to another **type** the scope in which counter resides gets **garbage collected** and gets **lost.**

I recommend you to read books from **kyle simpson**
***www.ydkjs.eu/***